# Xcode won't build to device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, build, executable

This problem has been KILLING me.  I've been working on this app for **8 Months**, and I am so close to finishing, I just can't seem to build for device.  Building for the simulator works fine, but device always gives me the SAME 2 errors.

The 1st Error:
[image: ddgd]
`"Instruction requires a CPU feature not currently enabled"`
From googling, I've found this probably means I'm not linking a binary I should be, but I'm not sure.

The 2nd Error:
[image]

If you can't read it, it says: `Generating JWFNS.app.dSYM ... error: unable to open executable '/Users/ajr1188/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JWFNS-azshgysfabycfagnebotitpcyaww/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/JWFNS.app/JWFNS'`

This is the big one.  I cannot seem to build the .app.dSYM file properly.  I went in and deleted the build folder, I looked at EVERY stackoverflow question I could find and tried changing any random thing mentioned in another question, but all of it is to no avail.  I'm so suck right now. AHH.  PLEASE. Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: Has this always been the case or did the project recently stop building on devices?

Comment: Have you tried to use GCC instead of LLVM ? Saying as not an expert, there's a lot of complaints in the web from linux users trying to compile this and that resulting your first error from Clang.

Comment: Yea I tried it, and it gave me 473 errors for random things like bad pointers and first use of a variable in a method...

Comment: Are you trying to use ARC on an older device?

Comment: yes, the device is an iphone that ran ios 4 for a while, but now it has ios 5.x

Comment: Do a build.  Go to the Log Navigator (View > Navigators > Show Log Navigator or command-7).  Click the top entry in the navigator.  See if the build log contains more details about the first error.  The second error is probably caused by the linker failing due to the first error.

Comment: The second error is indeed because of the first. When doing anything C, it's always a good idea to look at the first error, fix it, then rebuild, because 9 times out of 10 the other errors are a result of the first.

Comment: Is this a recent problem, or has it always been there? I don't think working on an app for any extended amount of time without trying it on all target devices every now and then is a food idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your project has become hopelessly corrupted.   One thing to try is to start a brand new project and copy/import all your sources/assets into the new project to see if that fixes the problem.

Another less nuclear (but perhaps more time consuming) approach is to binary search the build.  Exclude absolutely everything except main.m and see if that fixes the problem.  If it does, include half your sources, and buid again....repeat, trying to narrow in on the problem spot.   Maybe a file or group of files has received special build settings that don't belong there.

Answer (score 2):

I've had very similar problems, I cant remember the exact error message but it was very similar. Are you able to make a new project that will run on your device?
if so (and I know this sounds bad but it's worth a try) Create a new project and simply copy all the code and resources across and see if it still works. If it doesn't then there is something wrong with you code and you can continue trying to isolate the problem from there.
Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

check the frameworks you link to. there's a chance that you linked a framework (say quartz) of osx, instead of ios.

Comment: But my project is so big, its not convenient/practical to go through more than 150 classes and 20-25 frameworks

Comment: try this command line under your project's XXX.xcodeproj directory: `grep path project.pbxproj | grep framework | cut -d ";" -f 4` it'll show you the path(s) of linked frameworks. see if anything suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Answering in detail is probably going to take looking at your target settings. But it looks like you may be building for the wrong architecture. (It doesn't link, so there is no .dSYM symbol file.) For example, if you have only recently built for device, you probably created your project under an older Xcode, and it may not have the arm6/arm7 settings right.

To check, show the Build Settings for your target (not the project), and filter on Architecture.

Comment: Can you be more specific about Architecture settings.  Mine seem fine

Comment: Um, like I said, without seeing what you actually have, it's hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in build settings the architectures are armv6 and armv7. Also make sure that in .plist file, the "Application requires iPhone environment" is TRUE. Delete "Required device capabilities" in the .plist if present.